# Dragging a 2D image from an inventory and drop it as a 3d object

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, drag-and-drop, 2d

I'm a beginner with Unity. I want to drag a 2D image from my inventory and drop it in the scene as a 3D object. I can already drag and drop the 2D image in the scene. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Is it possible to destroy the 2D image and create a 3D object as soon as the drop action finished?

Comment: @ming060 I don't konw

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use ScreenToWorldPoint to map the 2d input to 3d coordinates then instantiate your 3d object.

Comment: I don't know how to do that :(